# Application run time estimation as mathematical formula/function

Tags: functions, computer-science

I'm writing a program that sends out text messages en masse. The program will split up the total number of texts into batches. These batches will be triggered, one at a time, after a set time period, but could technically be running concurrently (i.e. they don't actually wait on the last batch to finish before starting).

**The question**: How would I represent this in a formula or a function in order to estimate how long this process will take in minutes?

I never took calculus or advanced math, **so I'm sure I'm missing something here**. Any help is appreciated, but here's what I've got so far :

- let *x* be the total number of subscribers receiving texts
- let *y* be the frequency (in seconds) at which a batch is triggered
- let *z* be the number texts in each batch
- let *t* be the estimated time (in seconds) each text takes to send

$$f\left(x,y,z,t\right) = \frac1{60}\left(\lceil \frac xz \rceil y + tz\right)$$

So that:

$f\left(4600,60,100,.5\right) \approx $ 38 minutes

**Note**: the use of ceiling function $ \lceil \frac xz \rceil $ is because a batch will still be required to run as long as remaining texts $\ge 1$.